# How to put comma in number in Nepalese style in swift

Tags: ios, swift, number-systems

I am having trouble showing commas in price in Nepalese style . The number should be shown as 5,00,00,000 rather than 500,000,000 which i got using NSNumber Formatter.

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: you can use groupingSize to correctly format:

numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
numberFormatter.secondaryGroupingSize = 2